# TRI - Error importing content - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: packageName

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa

I'm getting the error listed below when I try & import the TRI content into my CM.  Any ideas?

> E:\software\SDL Tridion Reference Implementation\import\import.ps1 : Exception calling "StartImport" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: packageName."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + .\import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "http://server:81/"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [import.ps1], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FaultException`1,import.ps1

Comment: Did you check the troubleshooting section in the documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/undefined/undefined/GUID-E8F826CF-A360-4223-BF16-8F9E1AF231EA), if that didn't help, try running it with the `-Verbose` parameter and edit your question so you can include a bit more detail of the output so we can see what is really going wrong.