# DXA error while importing ALL publications

Tags: 2013, dxa, blueprint, installation

I am using Content Manager - Build 7.1. with Experience Manager 7.1.0.79 and the update version is SP1 on my VM installation for DXA 1.1

I am receiving the following error upon installation. Following is the error in VERBOSE output.

> PS D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL Digital
>   Experience Accelerator v1.1\impor t> .\import.ps1 -importType
>   all-publications -cmsUrl "http://localhost/" -verbose
>
> VERBOSE:
>   Performing operation "Import Digital Experience Accelerator into CMS"
>   on Target "System".
>
> VERBOSE: Performing operation "Import the
>   reference implementation" on Target "Tridion Content Manager".
>
> VERBOSE: Temp folder is 'C:\ProgramData\TRI\' VERBOSE: Import Package
>   FullPath is 'D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL
>   Digital Experience Accelerator
>   v1.1\import..\cms\all-publications.zip'
>
> VERBOSE: Permissions file
>   FullPath is 'D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL
>   Digital Experience Accelerator v1.1\import..\cms\permissions.xml'
>   Initializing types for ImportExport ... Done
>
> VERBOSE: Getting Core
>   Service Client with type 'Service' ...
>
> VERBOSE: Done Uploading package
>   ...
>
> VERBOSE: Package FullPath is
>   'D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL Digital
>   Experience Accelerator v1.1\import..\cms\all-publications.zip'
>
> VERBOSE: Temp Folder is 'C:\ProgramData\TRI\' VERBOSE: Mapping is
>   null? True VERBOSE: Uploading package from file ...
>
> VERBOSE:
>   PackageLocation is
>   'D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL Digital
>   Experience Accelerator v1.1\import..\cms\all-publications.zip'
>
> VERBOSE: Getting ImportExport Service Client with type 'Upload' ...
>
> VERBOSE: Done VERBOSE: Upload exception: Exception calling
>   "UploadPackageStream" with "1" argument(s): "There  was no endpoint
>   listening at
>   http://localhost/webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details."
>
> VERBOSE: Done Importing content ...
>
> VERBOSE: Getting
>   ImportExport Service Client with type 'Service' ...
>
> VERBOSE: Done
>
> D:\Tridion_Installation_Software\Extensions\DXA\SDL Digital Experience
>   Accelerator v1.1\import\import.ps1 : Exception calling "StartImport"
>   with "2" argument(s): "There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost/webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/basicHttp
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details." At line:1 char:1
>   + .\import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "http://localhost/" -verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [import.ps1], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndpointNotFoundException,import.ps1

I have tested the end point and it works as expected.

> http://localhost//webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc

Please note that I have not tested Content Porter client and I may have some configurations yet to complete for CP client to work fine with ImportExport service. I also have an existing blueprint that is already available. In that case, should I try a manual import using CP as suggested [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/installing-dxa-into-an-existing-blueprint).

I notice a duplicate of this question [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11290/tri-error-importing-content-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-packagenam), but it was never answered and hence I am posting a new one.

*Update*

I have also checked the Tridion cd_core log and did not notice any WARNING or error messages. Based on the IIS log for browsing the service, I noticed the following

```
GET /webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc - 80 MYUSERNAME 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/40.0.2214.111+Safari/537.36 - localhost 200 0 0 1643 376 1880
```

It status code is 200 OK

The IIS log while trying to Import is as follows

```
2015-09-29 14:12:27 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 POST /webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/basicHttp - 80 - 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 - - localhost 404 0 0 210 938 29
```

Am I missing any Authorization or Authentication rules?

Comment: The error you are getting is quite different from the other post; your error is quite explicit in what the problem is: the Import/Export Service endpoints are not responding.  Maybe an IIS log and failed request trace (for the CM website) can provide more insight?

Comment: The IIS log entry you have added is for a browser request (see user-agent) and probably corresponds to your test request.  Don't you see other requests for another user-agent?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Rick! I have updated the question with the observation.

Comment: Ok, so the IIS log confirms that a POST on the basicHttp endpoint yield a HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.  Check the web.config of the webservices web app (which contains both Import/Export service and Core Service) if the basicHttp endpoint is properly configured.  Have ypu maybe configured the endpoint for HTTPS? That is currently not supported by the DXA import script (that is: it requires manual changes to the script).